# spring security saml "unable to configure IDP"/set "metadata trust to false

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using spring security saml extension and AD FS for SSO purpose. I learn that the "metadataTrustCheck" can be set to "false", however, currently most the information I got is for
`<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">`
instand, I used

`bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider` and complete securityContext.xml file is like

```xml
    <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.lang.String">http://ADFS/Fedrationmetadata.xml</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="int">5000</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Anyone can advise how to add/comment "metadataTrustCheck" property in above configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Modify my question:   However, currently most the information I got is for <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider> but I am using <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">

Comment: @vladimír-schäfer